# Union between databases in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Hello I am making union between 2 databases, they are with same structure table:

```
use App\map1_weather;
use App\map2_weather;

$weather2 = map2_weather::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
->selectRaw('recordtime,tempout as temp_map2_weather,hitemp');
$weather = map1_weather::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
->selectRaw('recordtime,tempout,hitemp')
->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
->union($weather2)
->get();
```

The error that I have is:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "map2_weather" does not exist LINE 1
```

Is it the right aproach? The goal is to display 2 columns "teomput" in one table from different DBs

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to multiple databases. You need to specify database connection on both models if you are using multiple database collection, the error is due to your default db connection is not able to located some table used in query.

Specify connection property in both models `map1_weather` and `map2_weather`

Just add this line `protected $connection = "connection_name";`

Comment: I have protected $connection properties with different names in both models

Comment: Then it could be wrong table name, specify $table property in model with correct table name.

Comment: The two models working good in saparate controllers

Comment: A union between different connections doesn't generally work because you can have different servers per connection and you can't (easily) do queries across databases especially not when they might be different software (e.g. MySQL and SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Union across different database connections is not really allowed. If your table is on the same database you can probably just refer to the table using its full DB.table name instead of using a different connection e.g.

```
class map1_weather extends Model {
    protected $table = 'db.map1_weathers';
    // Don't specify a different connection. It might not be needed

}
```

Of course you can keep the connection variable as well if you want to but it will be ignored when doing operations like joins and unions since they don't generally work across different database connections (which might be on different databases using different technologies)

Comment: Ok, can you guide me how to acomplish this using eloquent with joins? Link or something?

Comment: If you just change the table name in the model then everything else should be handled for you. If there are any issues with this then do update your question with them